# Maven test log in Spring Boot application is not using configured Logback appender

Tags: spring-boot, maven, logback

I have Spring boot application and am using logback for logging purpose. I have defined STDOUT appender in logback file that formats log line as per pattern (logback file code attached). However when I run "mvn clean install" from command line I don't see same pattern getting applied on spring generated logs though same are getting applied on logs I have written.( see logs attached). I suspect behind the scene some other spring/maven appender is responsible for this behaviour.

Thanks in advance for any leads!

Logs generated by "mvn clean install"

```
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.856 s - in com.analytics.dao.sys.func.workflow.RecruitingWorkflowFactDaoTest
[INFO] Running com.analytics.dao.sys.func.workflow.FuncTest
22-12-2019 17:17:27.678 [main]
                ERROR c.a.d.e.LogTest - This is test error
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.096 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.analytics.dao.sys.func.workflow.FuncTest
[ERROR] FuncTest  Time elapsed: 1.095 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 

### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'xyz'.
### The error may exist in com.analytics/dao/mybatis/sys/maps/func/func.xml
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'random-pwd' 
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'xyz'.
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name 'xyz'.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
```

logback-test.xml

```
<configuration>
    <!-- <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" /> -->
    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread])
                %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %replace(%msg){"PASSWORD\s*=.*","Password=xxxxx"}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.analytics" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Where have you placed logback-test.xml ?

Comment: The logback-test.xml is placed at src/test/resources.